# primefaces accordion panel within single form - validation only on opened tab

Tags: jsf, primefaces, validation, accordion

I have checked around but I didn't found a clear example on how to submit the accordion using a single form. 
The problem I find is when I want to process (validate) only fields of the opened tab.

The structure of my page is as follows:

```
<h:form>
    <p:accordionPanel activeIndex="#{bean.selectedTab}">
        <p:ajax event="tabChange" listener="#{bean.tabChangeListener}"/>

        <p:tab title="Tab1" id="t1">
            <p:inputText id="reqField1" required="true"/>
        </p:tab>
        <p:tab title="Tab2" id="t2">
            <p:inputText id="reqField2" required="true"/>
        </p:tab>
   </p:accordionPanel>

   <p:commandButton update="list" immediate="true" actionListener="#{bean.addRecord}"/>                     
</h:form>
```

method:

```
@SessionScoped
public class Bean{
    public void tabChangeListener(AjaxBehaviorEvent evt){
        AccordionPanel panel = (AccordionPanel) evt.getComponent();
        // getLoadedTabs() returns an empty list
        String currentlyLoadedTabId = panel.getLoadedTabs().get(this.selectedTab).getClientId(); 

    }
}
```

Is there anyway to specify the id of the currently opened tab as part of the process attribute in p:commandButton tag?

***UPDATE***
When Tab1 is open, on submit, I want to be validated only reqField1 and not reqField2. Viceversa, when Tab2 is open, I want to be validated only reqField2 and not reqField1.

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

1. Bind the `activeIndex` of the accordionPanel to a backing bean int attribute

   ```
   activeIndex="#{myBean.selectedTab}"
   ```
2. Get the `id` of the currently selected tab using the bound `activeIndex`. To do this in your `actionListener`, get a handle on the accordion panel

   EDIT: Since your `actionListener` has been set to `immediate`, the `activeIndex` and   `selectedTab` will need to be updated via ajax. Add the following `<p:ajax/>` to your    accordionPanel

   ```
   <p:ajax event="tabChange" listener="#{bean.tabChangeListener}" />
   ```

   In your backing bean, you'll now have

   ```
   public void (AjaxBehaviorEvent evt){
    AccordionPanel panel = (AccordionPanel) evt.getComponent();
    String currentlyLoadedTabId = panel.getLoadedTabs().get(this.selectedTab).getClientId(); 

   }
   ```
3. Using the the `id` you got from 2 above, you can include that in the JSF list of things to be rerendered using ajax on the server side. In the same action listener method:

   ```
    FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getPartialViewContext().getRenderIds().add(currentlyLoadedTabId);
   ```

Alternatively, you might just consider placing a command button in each of those tabs and having a form in each tab as well. This way, each command button processes only it's own parent form

Comment: thanx for the answer. how can get be fired myActionListener()? is your myActionListener() method the equivalent of #{bean.addRecord} in my example? If yes, that is exactly the problem, that I can dot get in the backing bean method since validation process do not let me.

Comment: @Ermal, set `immediate="true"` on the `<p:commandButton/>` to be able to carry out it's processing *before* the validation phase

Comment: Ok, with immediate="true" I can enter in myActionListener() method and 'evt.getComponent().findComponent("myPanel").getLoadedTabs();' returns an empty list of Tab's object. Does it sound correct to you? What I noticed else, is that on tab changed, setSelectedTab() is not being called. If I remove required="true" to all fields in the tabs, setSelectedTab() is been called correctly on each change tab event.

Comment: @Ermal, that may be because you're calling `getLoadedTabs()` pretty early in the lifecyle. Is the `activeIndex` variable set? because now that I think of it, even that will always be incorrect if it's called too early. Add a `<p:ajax/>` to update the value of `selectedTab` and set the `currentlyLoadedTab` immediately the tab is changed. I've updated my answer to include this

Comment: @Ermal, if you're going to include ajax on your page, now your backing bean *must* be `@ViewScoped`

Comment: Thanks again for the answer @kolossus.My backing bean is `SessionScoped` and with all your modifications I can not enter in `tabChangeListener()` when tab is changed.If i ommit `required="true"` I can enter but still getLoadedTabs() returns an empty list. This all said I am really confused if this will resolve my problem :) What I want, is simply to validate only fields of opened tab on submit.

Comment: @Ermal, why don't you just have a command button inside a each panel pane, with each panel pane containing a single form? That way, the command button can be setup to submit only the enclosing form and you can do away with all these issues

Comment: Because I have other fields outside accordion which I want to read in the backing bean.This will make me have another more form.Before I go for that solution, or another one equivalent, I thought was another easy way for this specific.I am going to restore the title in my orginal request. hope is ok for you :) thanx for your support.