# how to get which tab is clicked when accordion is loaded intially on a page

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

I have an accordion panel with tabs containing name of students. I select on one of the tab and choose edit. I am calling a tab change listener and getting student object and trying to edit it works fine.

But My problem is when for the first time Accordion loads, even though I select on the tab,and click on edit, I will get not get student object. Its giving me null pointer exception. since Tab change event does not get called for the first time it loads. How do I solve this?

```
private StudBean formBean;

    public StudBean  getFormBean() {
        if(formBean==null){
            formBean= new StudBean();
        }

        return formBean;
    }

    public void onTabChange(TabChangeEvent event) {
        formBean = (StudBean) event.getData();
    }


public String edit(){


            formBean = testDelegate.getDetails(formBean.getName(),formBean.getId());


        return "/ui/EditStudent?faces-redirect=true";
    }




<p:commandButton process="@this" value="edit"  action="#{testBean.edit}" >

    <p:accordionPanel  value="#{testBean.students}" var="stud">  
                  <p:ajax event="tabChange"  listener="#{testBean.onTabChange}" immediate="true"/>
                  <p:tab title="#{stud.name}">
```

Comment: post your bean code and xhtml

Comment: @rags: For the first time when accordion loads, I click on first tab and click on edit. Tab change listener is not called and throws null pointer exception. and if I click on some other tab many times , and try to edit , listener is called and I will get  student object and every thing works fine.

Comment: In @PostConstruct method, initialise your formBean with the first student. This should solve the problem

Comment: @rags: but now the problem is, only the first student tab is opened every time.

Comment: Check whether onTabChange is getting correct student by printing  formBean.studentName etc....

Comment: ya i Checked, Tabchange event is not fired properly.form bean is not updating. If accordion different tabs clicked then tab change event is fired.. I mean If I click of student1 tab no event fired, student2 no event is fired, 3 student now tab change event is fired..

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/25757/discussion-between-shreekanth-and-rags)

Comment: refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13324380/primefaces-accordion-panel-within-single-form-validation-only-on-opened-tab for handling active tab.