# Tab change event of prime faces accordion doesnot fire for the first two times

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

Tab change event  of prime faces accordion does not fire for the first two times.I am using primeFaces3.4 and jsf2. Can Any body have a work around for this.

Comment: Please post your relevant code.

Comment: please go through this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15245275/how-to-get-which-tab-is-clicked-when-accordion-is-loaded-intially-on-a-page

Comment: @BalusC: can you please help me in this.